# Pagination in Python and Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm a newbie in Python development. I want to pagination my page in Django. I create a dropdown list for user choose number items want display in view. Ex: When i choose '10' in dropdown list and click submit button then the view display 10 items, but when I click 'next' or 'previous' button then the view display 25 items by default I set when loading items before choose value in dropdown list. Now I want when i click 'next' or 'previous' it will display 10 items look like I chosen in dropdown list. How can I do that. This is my code

**view.py:**

```
def listing(request):
    people = Person.objects.all()
    if "dropdown" in request.POST:
        per_page = request.POST["dropdown"]
    else: per_page = 25
    paginator = Paginator(people, per_page)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        people = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        people = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        people = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render_to_response('crud\index.html', RequestContext(request, {'people': people, 'per_page': per_page}))
```

and this is code file index.html

```
{% if people %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <p>
            <select name="dropdown">
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        {% for person in people %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ person.phone }}</td>
                <td>{{ person.age }}</td>
                <td><a href="delete/{{ person.id }}">Delete</a></td>
                <td><a href="edit/{{ person.id }}">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="pagination">
        <span class="step-links">
            {% if people.has_previous %}
                <a href="?page={{ people.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
            {% endif %}

            <span class="current">
                Page {{ people.number }} of {{ people.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>

            {% if people.has_next %}
                <a href="?page={{ people.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
        </div>
    </table>
</form>
{% else %}
    <p>No people in the database</p>
{% endif %}
{% if per_page %}
    <p>You picked {{ per_page }}.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The page resets to 25 because you don't have the POST parameter anymore when the client triggers the navigation.

The way to do it is to add another get parameter with the number of results per page, so every page would be `?page=x&pagination=10`

Your form could link directly to this by converting it to a get method and changing the name of the input to the name of the get parameter. You would have to adapt your navigation links as well in consequence.